# Using tf.equal to compare two tensors of unequal length?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors, A and B (both first-rank vectors). B is a subset of A. I want to know the locations of B in A, i.e. for each element of A, is A_{i} in B. I have tried using tf.equal, for which I'd expect a tensor of booleans and then use tf.where, but with little success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

My answer if anyone is interested:

```
def compare(x):
        return tf.equal(result,x)

loss_index = tf.reshape(tf.slice(tf.where(tf.map_fn(compare,B,dtype = tf.bool)),[0,1],[q,1]),[q])
```

Where q is the length of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it without `map_fn` (which internally uses a while loop which doesn't parallelize as well on the GPU) by first tiling A size-of-B times, reshaping A, using the fact that `tf.equal` will broadcast, and then using `tf.reduce_any` on the dimension you tiled over to get a vector in the shape of B.